# Can water thrown from window break car below?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, water, collision, estimation

Let's say I live at the 5th floor in a street where most of the nights drunk people scream and sing loudly.

Could a buck of water thrown from said floor, from the window, onto the street, possibly damage parked cars?

The buck may contain around 7 liters of water.

I'm asking if is it possible to scientifically proof the possibility to damage cars (metal, glass, plastic parts) with the said amount of water from the given height.
I'm interested in any possible kind of damage, not only grave ones.

Possibly, a rough percentage of chances of this happening would be welcome.

The temperature of the environment may vary from -40 to 40 degree celsius.
The water temperature is the average tap water.

Edit to clarify the situation: the question wanted to be as generic as possible, but I'm asking this because a person I know does this regularly and I want to know the possible consequences.

Comment: In general, it's possible, anything stopped fast enough can make an arbitrary force.

Comment: I don't think we should be giving advice on potentially dangerous scenarios.

Comment: @keith-mcclary I sort of agree but any real world scenario could be defined as potentially dangerous and it's better to warn people when something is dangerous rather than say nothing.

Comment: While I think of it actually causing damage to the cars would cost you money and maybe a charge of some sort.  If your action resulted in any form of injury then you're moving up to assault or worse.  Maybe eviction.  *And* you'll loose a perfectly good buck(et) to boot.  And anyone who doesn't sue you after being doused in water at -40 C would be an idiot or not have heard of lawyers.

Comment: @StephenG, I don't think Fez mean throwing the bucket itself, only its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring wind resistance the water will be falling at a speed of $v = \sqrt{2gh},$  so somewhere in the range of $\text{10-20 m/s}$ at those heights. An exposed surface of area $A$ will confront a mass flow per unit time of $\Phi = \rho~A~v$ and will change its velocity from around $v$ to around $0$, and this change in momentum per unit time will be experienced as a reaction force. The pressure experienced in decelerating the water is therefore of the magnitude $\rho~v^2,$ which for water at these speeds ranges from $\text{100-400 kPa}$.

Just for comparison I am a large man, my feet are about $\text{600 cm}^2$ in area total, I am maybe $\text{130 kg}$, and therefore the pressure involved in me standing on something is roughly $\text{21 kPa}.$

So we're talking that this will have roughly the effect of a stack of mes (that is, me giving a piggyback ride to a copy of me giving a piggyback ride to a copy of ...) somewhere between 5 and 20 tall, walking on said car. I would certainly anticipate damage from that sort of thing, even if it were only for a short time. It would probably not break the suspension, say, but it might be capable of cracking a windshield or even, if it hit the wrong part too hard, taking off a side-view mirror.

Answer (score 4):

No scientific answer, but based on having seen people throwing water from a bucket at -30C from a high floor, chances are water splits in droplets that freeze before reaching tbe ground and drop down like a nasty hail. However, because this process is random, thare is a good chance a large amount of water takes a shape of a big drop and flies down unsplit. In this case it would crash a car roof or windshield or easily break someone's neck and potentially even crash the skull even in summer. Chances of this happening are too real to neglect.

Please note that on a high speed impact water does not have enough time to act softly as a fluid, but hits almost as hard as a rock. So don't do it. There is a better way.  Move to a better place. Instead of hydrodynamics, study the laws of motion :)

Comment: "hits almost as hard as a rock"  is the relevant part here. Would one throw a 7 kilo rock from the window of the fifth floor? even one kilo could be lethal falling on the head.

Comment: If the bucket is inverted rather than sloshed sideways, the water will start falling as a single mass. If air resistance dispersed say a third of the water into droplets, this would leave about 4.5kg hitting in a single mass at around 10 m/s = 36 km/hr. If a baseball weighs just under 150g (= 1/30th of the water), does the water hit with the same momentum as a baseball travelling at 30 x 36 = 1080 km/h?

Comment: @Chappo: I believe your calculation is correct. Even if in reality the impact is several times smaller due to the air resistance and what not, such a hit in the head can easily be fatal anyway.